# How to send firestore timestamps through FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a document in firestore which contains a timestamp field and i want to send it as payload of a firebase cloud message. I am using the admin sdk from node.js and i want to receive the message on android.
Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timestamp contains two integer values, seconds and nanoseconds.  If you want to serialize that timestamp to send it to another piece of code, all you have to do is send both of those values to the other code, then reconstitute the timestamp using [Timestamp constructor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#public-constructor-summary) that takes both of those values as input.